# Can JDBC be used with Cassandra?

Tags: jdbc, cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-jdbc-driver

I have generic functions in my project that handle each database type, whether it's MySql or Oracle and more by using Statement and JDBC Connection.
However when I try using them for supporting Cassandra, it doesn't work so I created a new function just for Cassandra- that connects via Cluster.
Is there an option to use the following without getting exceptions and not Cluster?

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://TheIp:9042", userName, passWord);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
```

The dependencies I have on my POM Maven are;

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to connect via JDBC using the **[Simba JDBC Driver for Apache Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/driver-matrix/doc/driver-matrix.html#_jdbc_and_odbc_drivers)** provided by DataStax for free. You can download the driver and the manual from [DataStax Downloads](https://downloads.datastax.com/#odbc-jdbc-drivers).

However, if you're already developing your app in Java then have a look at the [Cassandra Java driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/). Here's a sample code which shows how to connect to and read from a Cassandra cluster:

```
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.*;

public class ConnectDatabase {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // Create the CqlSession object:
       try (CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder()
           .addContactPoint(new InetSocketAddress("1.2.3.4", 9042))
           .withLocalDatacenter("DC1")
           .build()) {
           // Select the release_version from the system.local table:
           ResultSet rs = session.execute("select release_version from system.local");
           Row row = rs.one();
           //Print the results of the CQL query to the console:
           if (row != null) {
               System.out.println(row.getString("release_version"));
           } else {
               System.out.println("An error occurred.");
           }
       }
       System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the elaborated answer, The code block you gave me is similar to mine with Cluster. Just a question about the JDBC Simba driver, how can I add it to the project which is being shared by a lot of people through git? Can I add it as Maven dependency on POM?

Comment: Although the Simba JDBC driver is free to download, you cannot distribute it as part of your app. All users must accept the terms & conditions when they download the driver from the DataStax Downloads site. Cheers!